# How to develop the logic of code so as to check all possible permutations in a 3x3 matrix?

Tags: c++, matrix, permutation

I am making a program to check if a given matrix is a magic square or not. (a square where the numbers in each row or column or diagonally add up to the same number). The program can check any 3x3 matrix successfully but now I need it to be such that it prints out all the possible magic squares.

So, it has to check all possible 3x3 matrix (value each element of matrix ranging between 1 - 9). It would be 10^9 combinations (right?)

I think this can be done by putting 9 nested for loops but that would be exhausting. Is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: IIRC magic matrices is more about the sums being equal than the actual combinations themselves. Also, you can make sub functions to logically separate your work. It won't be faster but it will be easier to understand.

Comment: Ranging beetween 0-9(not 1-9) it will be 10^9. What do you mean by easier? In terms of speed you can not change it as in any case you have to end up with the same number of unique combinations.

Comment: lol you're right Alexandru... no matter what I do, it will have to check all those combos... I'm new to programming. Yes, I get it now that the speed of execution cannot be changed.

Comment: I was just wondering if there was an alternative way to do this..

Comment: [There is](https://ideone.com/neTN7a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each allowed matrix is a run of nine numbers from [0,9], every nine digit number from 000000000 to 999999999 corresponds to one of the matrices you want to check. Iterating through these matrices therefore basically means counting in nine digit numbers, and reading the digits off to get the matrix elements. The problem is that reading those digits takes time, and you're doing it 10^9 times. If you were counting by incrementing an `int` then you'd have to convert to a string each time and read off the characters, or use floor and modulo division each time to pick out one digit, neither of which are acceptable.

The solution is to represent the matrix as an array of 9 `int`s, one for each digit of that nine digit number, and count by incrementing those `int`s. Then reading off digits is as simple as accessing array elements. You can count like this with a recursive function:

```
void count(int * matrix, int pos, int * magicCount)
{
do
{
    if(pos<8)
    {
        count(matrix, pos+1, magicCount);
    }
    else
    {
        if(isMagic(matrix))
        {
            (*magicCount)++;
        }
    }
    matrix[pos] += 1;
}
while(matrix[pos] < 10);
for(; pos<9; pos++)
{
    matrix[pos] = 0;
}
}
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_coded_decimal